# Flasgger - Upload File

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flasgger

I am working on a project that requires to upload a file via flasgger UI. I modified my conf based on Swagger docs but doesn't seem to work. Below is my conf. Please, let know the mistake.

```
"""
This API let's you train word embeddings
Call this api passing your file and get the word embeddings.

---
tags:
  - Train (Word Embeddings)
consumes:
  - multipart/form-data  
parameters:
  - in: formData
    name: body
    required: true
    description: Upload your file.
responses:
  500:
    description: ERROR Failed!
  200:
    description: INFO Success!
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/txt_embeddings'
"""
```

Comment: Figured out.   Had to add type parameter as well with "file" as value under parameters.

Comment: I tried using the type parameter but the file keeps loading when i upload it. Any idea what the issue would be?

Comment: you can use this template   "parameters": [
        {
            "in": "formData",
            "name": "file",
            "description": "Accepts a valid .xls file",
            "required": True,
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "in": "formData",
            "name": "created_by",
            "description": "Accepts a valid user name",
            "required": True,
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing 'type: file', the following worked for me:

```
...
parameters:
    - name: file
      required: false
      in: formData
      type: file
...
```